# Timeout exception (wcf) while running python script

Tags: wcf, timeout, net.tcp

I am running a python script that controls an ADI software named ACE capturing data remotely through port 8080. The ACE will attempt to create an IPC server on the port number. It takes around 12 minutes to capture 1 data set. The script runs normally for capture under 10 minutes. I suspects that the exception occurs because the default ReceiveTimeout is 10 minutes.

I adjusts the ReceiveTimeout in the SMSvcHost.exe.config file but it still not fix the issue. Other threads suggest that I need to adjust the ReceiveTimeout in app.config/ web.config. I am not sure how to locate these file. I am worried I might make changes to the wrong config file. Please advise!

Tracing Information:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKeHA.png

Here is the error message

> This request operation sent to net.tcp://localhost:8080/ did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:10:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

Comment: I suggest that you can provide a configuration file so that it can help you solve the problem. You can try to configure sendTimeout, maxBufferSize="2147483647"', maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647", maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647", maxReceivedMessageSize, MaxItemsInObjectGraph. You can refer to this link.https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Comment: Am I supposed to adjust these values for the config files of both client and server? For client side, is SMSvcHost.exe.config the right file to adjust?

Comment: Make sure that the client and server are consistent, because I can't guarantee your specific error location, so I can't be sure, I can only suggest you try to modify it yourself. Care should be taken when modifying the contents of the 'SMSvcHost.exe.config' file, you can review the documentation.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-the-net-tcp-port-sharing-service#when-to-modify-smsvchostexeconfig